# SparkSQL- Add new column to DataFrame based on the aggregation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Having the following DataFrame:

```
+--------+----------+------------+
|user_id |level     |new_columns |
+--------+----------+------------+
|4       |B         |null        |
|6       |B         |null        |
|5       |A         |col1        |
|3       |B         |col2        |
|5       |A         |col2        |
|2       |A         |null        |
|1       |A         |col3        |
+--------+----------+------------+
```

I need to convert each `not null` value of the `new_columns` column to a new column, which should be done based on the aggregation on the `user_id` column. The desired output would be

```
+--------+-------------+------+
|user_id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+--------+------+------+------+
|4       | null | null | null |
|6       | null | null | null |
|5       |  A   |  A   | null |
|3       | null |  B   | null |
|2       | null | null | null |
|1       | null | null |  A   |
+--------+-------------+------+
```

As you can see, the value of the new columns comes from the `level` column in the base DF. I know how to use the `withColumn` method to add new columns on a DF but here the critical part is how to add new columns on the aggregated DF (for the case of the `user_id = 5`).

Every hint based on the **DataFrame API** would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `pivot`:

```
val df2 = df.groupBy("event_id")
            .pivot("new_columns")
            .agg(first("level"))
            .drop("null")
      
df2.show
+--------+-------------+------+
|user_id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+--------+------+------+------+
|4       | null | null | null |
|6       | null | null | null |
|5       |  A   |  A   | null |
|3       | null |  B   | null |
|2       | null | null | null |
|1       | null | null |  A   |
+--------+-------------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks, I need the new column's names to come dynamically from the base DF (`new_columns`), not hardcoded.

Comment: @SoheilPourbafrani check edited answer? it should also work without the list of names, but need to drop a column called null.

Comment: In the case I have other columns in the DF as well, could you tell me please how can I have them in the result? I updated my question with sample data.

Comment: @SoheilPourbafrani then you would need to group by all the other columns too

Comment: I updated the question with the first version of the input. Pls revert your question if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the non-null values from `new_columns` first before doing pivot :

```scala
val nonNull = df.select("new_columns").filter("new_columns is not null").distinct().as[String].collect

val df1 = df.groupBy("user_id")
            .pivot("new_columns", nonNull)
            .agg(first("level"))

df1.show

//+-------+----+----+----+
//|user_id|col3|col1|col2|
//+-------+----+----+----+
//|      1|   A|null|null|
//|      6|null|null|null|
//|      3|null|null|   B|
//|      5|null|   A|   A|
//|      4|null|null|null|
//|      2|null|null|null|
//+-------+----+----+----+
```